# add circle with specific style to canvas

Tags: css, html, canvas

Hi i do HTML 5 game in canvas. I already done somthing inside of canvas and i need to add it into. I need add div that looks like planet and rotate 360°. Here is link to demo. If you know somehow how to do it ill be glad.

http://jsfiddle.net/065aey2u/26/

```
<canvas></canvas>
<div id=earth"></div>

#earth{
styling of earth its complicated and contains before and after styling so i 
cant just drow it into canvas. Look demo and let me know if you know how to 
draw into canvas

}
```

Comment: what is the issue exactly?

Comment: I need to add content of div(rotating planet) into canvas

Comment: in this case you need to read more about canvas to understand how to add image, appy rotation, etc etc .... Don't simply wait for a ready code, better learn by yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way for you to simply put a `<div>` inside the `<canvas>` element and make it magically draw on the canvas. That said, you can draw/animate this image the same way you are right now inside the canvas with JavaScript instead.

I'm not going to just write all of the code for you, but I will explain some concepts for you to research.

**To animate:**

- `requestAnimationFrame(functionName)`

  - Update the canvas element every frame
  - Draw everything inside that function to render every frame

**To update image**

- Use the `rotate()` and `translate()` methods (similar to your css)

**To draw circle**

```
ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.clip();
ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height);
```

[Reference for every Canvas method you will need to use](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D)

[Reference for requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)

Alternatively, you could simply style the `<div>` to be on top of the canvas, but  you cannot draw it inside the canvas without using JS.

Comment: thanks man you help me a lot. I am good with javascript and HTML but drawing in canvas is all new for me so iam glad you help me.